# ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation onError not called after view model fails to validate on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-validate

I have modified unobtrusive validation script to replace error messages with qtips.
To do so I have modified `onError` method in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

This works great until I submit form and model fails to validate on server side (my view models implements `IValidatableObject`). When this occurs, the default spans with errors are displayed but `onError` is no longer invoked.

Furthermore, when a field that has an error is corrected, the error message no longer disappears immediately as it did before submit...

Does anyone know how to "re-enagage" unobtrusive validation after submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article:

[ASP.NET MVC: Displaying Client and Server Side Validation Using qTip Tooltips](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/asp-net-mvc-displaying-client-and-server-side-validation-using-qtip-tooltips/)

I've used what's described there and I got client & server (IValidatableObject) side errors displaying correctly.

Comment: Yes I used similar approach (I don't have AJAX submit and don't use jQuery UI), but my problem is that unobtrusive validation stops working after submit (onError is not firing)

Answer (score 0):

IValidatableObject is server side only.  If you want to support both server and client, then you need to implement a validation attribute that derives from IClientValidatable.